# what is user_id in google oauth command line example?

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth

Where is user_id supposed to come from in this example?

Using the command line example from here:
https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby

I've only changed the example by removing the '/path/to/' and there is a client_secrets.json in my working directory.

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'

OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file('client_secrets.json')
token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(
  :file => 'tokens.yaml')
authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(client_id, scope, token_store)

credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
if credentials.nil?
  url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(base_url: OOB_URI )
  puts "Open #{url} in your browser and enter the resulting code:"
  code = gets
  credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
    user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
end
```

Running this code prints out a url to plug into my browser.  The url takes me to a consent screen.  After I accept, I'm given a code to plug back into the terminal.

Then I get the error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user_id' for main:Object
```

... because obviously user_id is not defined, but where do I get it?

Alternately, is there a better, newer, or better documented oauth 2.0 library I should be using for Ruby in combination with all of the youtube apis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user_id` should the email address of the person who clicks the link.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that is wondering I believe that you can safely set
    user_id='default'
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ruby

This will present the user with a "choose account" dialog if the user is redirected to the authorizer.get_authorization_url